# How to generate private, public and ethereum addresses using web3.py?

Tags: addresses, private-key, python, web3.py, public-key

I want to know the process of generating the keys for ethereum using **web3.py**. How to generate the keys if I install my ether node.

```
from web3 import Web3, HTTPProvider, IPCProvider
web3 = Web3(HTTPProvider('http://localhost:8545'))
```

I configured the node. Now, what is the method to get the keys (private, public and ether address)? Please explain.

Comment: Since you mention the node, I would assume you mean to create a Hosted Private Key in your Local Node. If not, please update your question. See http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/web3.eth.account.html#local-vs-hosted-keys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`web3.personal.newAccount(password)`](http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.personal.html#web3.personal.newAccount) method:

> Generates a new account in the node’s keychain encrypted with the given `passphrase`. Returns the address of the created account.
>
> ```
> py>> web3.personal.newAccount('the-passphrase')
> ['0xd3cda913deb6f67967b99d67acdfa1712c293601']
> ```

*Note that for security purposes, nodes do not expose the private key over the `json-rpc` api that web3 uses. I'm not aware of a way to access your public key either.*

If you want [local keys](http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.eth.account.html#local-vs-hosted-keys) instead of hosted keys, then check out: [How can I generate a wallet in python?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/32940/how-can-i-generate-a-wallet-in-python)

---

*Edit*: it seems you really want **both** things: a local key and a hosted key at the same time. To accomplish that, you could create the key in the node and then extract it. That involves finding the file and decrypting it.

Where your keyfile is kept depends on your choice of node, OS, and configuration. I'll assume the default `geth` keystore folder: `~/.ethereum/keystore/`

You can [decrypt the keyfile](http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.eth.account.html#extract-private-key-from-geth-keyfile) using the eth-account method [`decrypt()`](http://eth-account.readthedocs.io/en/stable/eth_account.html#eth_account.account.Account.decrypt):

```
from eth_account import Account

with open('~/.ethereum/keystore/<your_keyfile_name>') as keyfile:
    keyfile_json = keyfile.read()

private_key = Account.decrypt(keyfile_json, '<you-account-password>')

# get some extra info about the private_key, like the address:
acct = Account.privateKeyToAccount(private_key)

ether_address = acct.address
```

You also asked about the public key, which is not an often used part of Ethereum, so there's no great API for it. You can use this non-public API, but note that these variable names could change at any time:

```
acct._key_obj.public_key
```

Comment: If I create local keys ( using some other libraries to generate private, public and ether address), Can I send them to the node to push the transaction ( after signing ) using `w3.eth.sendRawTransaction()`?

Comment: I want to use the local node which is controlled by me and also want to generate keys using the local node.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you **have been activated personal rpc of your geth**, to do this programatically **without hardcoding the keystore file directory path** in **python**, do the following:

```
from web3 import Web3
import eth_keys
from eth_account import account

w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider('http://127.0.0.1'))

password = 'password'
address = web3.personal.newAccount('password')

wallets_list = w3.geth.personal.list_wallets()
keyfile_path = (wallets_list[list(i['accounts'][0]['address'] for i in wallets_list).index(address)]['url']).replace("keystore://", "").replace("\\", "/")
keyfile = open(keyfile_path)
keyfile_contents = keyfile.read()
keyfile.close()
private_key = eth_keys.keys.PrivateKey(account.Account.decrypt(keyfile_contents, password))
public_key = private_key.public_key

private_key_str = str(private_key)
public_key_str = str(public_key)
```